# Shortcut keyboard shortcuts don't work

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I have this set up:

[image: Shortcut properties window]

However, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> doesn't do anything. I have tested other shortcuts that lead to other files and no keyboard shortcut works.

Comment: What window is in focus when you throw down the key combination? The only guaranteed target is to have your desktop itself in-focus. If additional programs are in focus they may or may not capture the key combinations before they have a chance to bubble back down to the OS depending on the program. On another random tangent, have you tried `Ctrl` + `Alt` combinations?

Comment: I do it when no other windows are open. And yes, `Ctrl` + `Alt` combos don't work.

Comment: I tried making a shortcut to a .bat file that launched this application, it still doesn't work. I also tried having the bat file simply come up, say a phrase and wait for user input, but it wouldn't start with shortcuts.